# Function to record student's names

Tags: python, function, loops, return

I'm trying to write a program in Python that takes a student's name and grade.I need this function to work for multiple students and then keep track of inputs so I can identify what student got the highest mark. I'm currently stuck on trying to get the loop to run again after the first inputs and also I don't know how to record the data. This is my attempt so far:

```
def banter(name= "", score = 0):
   student_no = int(input("How many student are there> "))
   while student_no > 0:
     name = input("Enter your name here > ")
     grade = int(input("Enter your grade here > "))
     student_no  = student_no - 1
     return name + str(grade)
banter()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `return` statement causes the `while` loop to exit. You need to store the student names and grades in something like a `list`, `dict`, or `list` of instances of a `class` of your own creation. Then return that outside the while loop.

Comment: [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are used in such cases (one attribute).

Comment: or classes @Yasin Yousif

Answer (score 0):

`return` breaks the loop, you can try this, create a `list` and `append` the data and return the `list` after the loop.

```
def banter(name= "", score = 0):
   student_no = int(input("How many student are there> "))
   name_grade = list()
   while student_no > 0:
     name = input("Enter your name here > ")
     grade = int(input("Enter your grade here > "))
     student_no  = student_no - 1
     name_grade.append(name+str(grade))
   return name_grade

banter()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really good class for this. Copy the following code it works very well. Basically what I did was I made it so student is an object, and every student has a grade and name that is assigned to them. So when you do Student(name, grade) it creates it and has a special output for each student. Then i just put them in a list and at the end I printed out the list.

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grade):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} has a grade of {}".format(self.name, self.grade)



students_list = []

x = int(input("How many students are there? "))

while x != 0:
    name = input("Enter the name: ")
    grade = input("Enter the grade: ")
    students_list.append(Student(name, grade))
    x-=1

for i in students_list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is in the last line in your function
`return name + str(grade)`

You're returning the value and thus exiting your loop.
You might want to store values in a `list` or a `dict`

for example

```
def banter(name= "", score = 0):
   student_no = int(input("How many student are there> "))
   student_data = {}
   while student_no > 0:
     name = input("Enter your name here > ")
     grade = int(input("Enter your grade here > "))
     student_data[name] = grade
     student_no  = student_no - 1
   return student_data

banter()
```

This stores the name and grade in a dictionary